# function executes too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with the following problem:

I want a function to create DIV tags to hold images and a second function to create the IMG tag and insert them in the DIVs created before. Works well with "alert messages". However without alerts, the second function runs before the first finished loading the DIV tags.

I think I need some kind of callback function worked in, but I have no clue how to do this.

Here is the code:

```
function imageLoader ()
     {         
     for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
             {
             checkPath = 'images/pic'i+'.png';
             $.ajax({
                     url: checkPath,
                     type:'HEAD',
                     success:
                             function() {
                                     //create DIVs t hold images
                                     $('.tools').append("<div class='tooling'></div>");
                                     }
                     });
             }
     // after creating DIVs, call function to create <img> tags
     appendix();  
     }
```

Thanks for helping out.

Regards,

frequent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, as Kos pointed out, you can't rely on the calls to complete in order, you'll have to get a little tricky to ensure that all your ajax calls have been completed.  Try something like this:

```
function imageLoader() {
    var ajaxCounter = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        checkPath = 'images/pic'
        i + '.png';
        $.ajax({
            url: checkPath,
            type: 'HEAD',
            success: function() {
                //create DIVs t hold images
                $('.tools').append("<div class='tooling'></div>");
                ajaxCounter++;
                if (ajaxCounter == 5) {
                    // after creating DIVs, call function to create <img> tags
                    appendix();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That should check to make sure you have the required number of ajax successes before executing the `appendix()` call.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what I was looking for, although if an img isn't there I'm stuck, am I?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.  You could get around that by returning something else in the case that an image isn't found, or setting a timeout and and executing the function when the time expires if it hasn't already been called.

Comment: I could add the failure section, also increase ajaxCounter++ if NO image was found and run appendix() from the failure if ajaxCounter == 5.

Comment: this way, ajaxCounter always increases, no matter if an image is found or not. Once ajaxCounter == 5, appendix is fired from either success or failure section. Would this work?

Comment: @Ender I like your answer better, you deserve the "Accept" :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell exactly what you're asking, but it looks like maybe you need to move your `appendix()` call into the success callback.  Remember that the `success` callback may not be executed before the `appendix` call in the code you presented.

```
function() {
  //create DIVs t hold images
  $('.tools').append("<div class='tooling'></div>");
  appendix();
}
```

Of course, you might not want this called 5 times inside your for loop.  Here's one way to make it call after the last success occurs, perhaps not the cleanest:

```
for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
  if(i == 5) {
    var succ = function() {
        //create DIVs t hold images
        $('.tools').append("<div class='tooling'></div>");
        appendix();
      };
  } else {
    var succ = function() {
        //create DIVs t hold images
        $('.tools').append("<div class='tooling'></div>");
      };
  }
  checkPath = 'images/pic'i+'.png';
  $.ajax({
    url: checkPath,
    type:'HEAD',
    success: succ
    });
}
```

Comment: I had the appendix(); "inside" success before, but then the function was called 5 times, so I moved it outside of the loop. I think your proposed solution is pretty much what I was trying to do. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

a) Create a variable to count how many times the `success` function callback has executed and run `appendix` only when this count equals the number of your ajax calls,

b) Register the `$.ajaxComplete` callback.

Answer (score 1):

The elegant way to do this is to use `$.when`:

```
function imageLoader(
    $.when.apply($, $.map(new Array(5), function (e, i) {
        var checkPath = 'images/pic' + (i + 1) +'.png',
            d = $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({
            url: checkPath,
            type:'HEAD',
            success: function () {
                d.resolve($('<div class="tooling">')
                              .append($('<img>').attr(src, checkPath)));
            },
            error: function () { d.resolve(null); }
        });

        return d.promise();
    })
    .then(function () {
        $('.tools').append(Array.prototype.slice(arguments));
    });
}
```

Comment: agree. 4 years later, that's how I do it, too :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could set async to false in $.ajax so it blocks execution.
Or, you could check *i* in the success callback, and if its 5, call appendix().

Comment: +1 for the former, -1 for the latter, as the ajax calls aren't guaranteed to finish in order.... right?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function imageLoader ()
>  {         
>  for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
>          {
>          checkPath = 'images/pic'i+'.png';
>          $.ajax({
>                  url: checkPath,
>                  type:'HEAD',
>                  success:
>                          function() {
>                                  //create DIVs t hold images
>                                  $('.tools').append("<div class='tooling'></div>", 
>                                      function(){
>                                          appendix();  
>                                      });
>                                  }
>                  });
>          }     
>  }
> ```